# is there any way to programmatically set a flag if a value is present in presto/athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have two tables A and B. A has columns X and Y. B has columns X and Z

on left joining A to B some of Y will have values and some won't

is there any way to add a flag to A if Y has value?

the equivalent of

select (if Y is not null then 1 else 0) as flag, X, Y from A left join B

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a flag in a table, however, the following query is using *coalesce* to give you the value from the *JOIN* or a different value otherwise

```
WITH A AS
    (SELECT '0001' as X, '2020-01-01' as Y UNION ALL
      SELECT '0002', '2020-01-02' UNION ALL
      SELECT '0003', '2020-01-03'),
     B as 
     (SELECT '0001' as X, 'YES' as Z UNION ALL
      SELECT '0003', 'YES')
select A.X, Y, coalesce(Z,'NO') as flag from A left join B on A.X = B.X
```

The output is

| X | Y | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0002 | 2020-01-02 | NO |
| 0001 | 2020-01-01 | YES |
| 0003 | 2020-01-03 | YES |

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an `EXISTS` check:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from b where b.x = a.x)
             then 'yes' else 'no'
        end) as flag
from a;
```

I don't recommend `LEFT JOIN` because that will multiply the number of rows if there are duplicates.